# Troubleshooting Major Garbage Collection Cause

Tags: java, performance, garbage-collection

I have a Java application running on Open SDK 1.7.0_95 64 bin environment and I am seeing two major garbage collection every hour which is hitting application response time to peek and I am intended to avoid it. As of now profiling my application using your-kit profile. Can anyone help me with the steps to  troubleshoot the cause of these major GCs so that I can avoid it if possible. Application is deployed on Jboss EAP 6.2 on Linux environment.

OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.6.4.0.el6_7-x86_64 u95-b00)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.95-b01, mixed mode)

Please let me know if anything else needed from my side.
Thanks in advance!
Regards,
Divya Garg

Comment: To start with you could post details about what your configuration is.  How big is your heap, what command line options you're using, etc?  Without that and without any profiling data this is an unanswerable question.  Long pauses in old gen are typically down to the need for the GC to run a full compaction.  This is the result of GC not being able to keep up with the rate of allocation or excessive fragmentation of the heap.  To start with try increasing the size of your heap. There are many other things to suggest but without more information, there's not much point.

Comment: -XX:+UseCompressedOops
-XX:+TieredCompilation
-Xmx1978m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-XX:+AggressiveOpts
-DOPENSHIFT_APP_UUID=59c0cc814930e9981c000923
-Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-Djboss.node.name=9d6nra5nfc4-9d6nra5nfc4.dmp-dev.ficoanalyticcloud.com
-Djgroups.bind_addr=127.107.196.129
-Dorg.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.COMPRESSION=on
-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2

Comment: Hi, currently I am testing my mocked service on a single JVM with 3GB memory and tried increasing the heap space from 1978MB to 3GB where major GC frequency changed from twice per hour to once in every 1.6 hours which is good but I am trying to get rid of it completely. Is it possible ? Found some classes which are not getting collected in minor GC and promoted to old GC. Please suggest what specifically I shoud analyze these classes or is this correct direction to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

The question you ask is of the kind "my car don't go fast enough what are the steps to find out what's going on". The answer to that is - consult a qualified auto repair service.

What you can try:

Turn on `-XX:+PrintGC` to see more of what's happenning.

Major GC once in an hour or so which halts the application is a hint to bad GC configuration. Normally it happens in memory-greedy apps which are given huge amount of memory. Then, when the time comes the GC has to clean several gigabytes which can halt processing for a few minutes. Check [parallel collector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/parallel.html) or, generally "garbage collection tuning" which is an art of its own.

You may (or may not) have a memory leak problem, profile to find out (like it seems you do). Profiling is also an art of its own. Look for biggest allocations and where they come from, try to find out why are they still referenced and can't be cleaned up.

Comment: The JVM I am using now Open SDK 1.7.0_95 64 is alreday using parallel collector. According to my analysis there is no memmory leak issue. I am trying the VM arg surviverRatio by reducing it and looks it can contribute to decrease the major GC frequency. Thanks